# Unable to See VirtualBox NGINX Sites

Tags: nginx, virtualbox

I'm trying to setup several Websites on an NGINX server running under Debian Linux locally inside Oracle VM VirtualBox.

**Versions:**
Oracle VM VirtualBox: 4.3.10, Debian: Wheezy, NGINX: 1.2.1

The */etc/nginx/nginx.conf* file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {
    autoindex on;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    error_page 404 = /usr/share/nginx/www/404.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The */etc/nginx/sites-available/default* file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    server_name vmhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.htm /index.html =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
   location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
      return 403;
      error_page 403 /403_error.html;
   }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The */etc/nginx/sites-available/testsitea* file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mytest;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/testfolder/public;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

The symbolic links:

```
root@debian-nginx:/etc# ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Mar 17 13:47 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Mar 25 14:30 testsitea -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/testsitea
```

When I send my browser to `http://192.168.1.45/`, I see the expected "Welcome to nginx!"
If I set the browser address to `http://192.168.1.45/vmhost`, I also see "Welcome to nginx!"

When I direct my browser to `http://192.168.1.45/mytest` what I expect to see is the static index.html file of my test site. What I actually see is the "Welcome to nginx!" file.

The error.log file shows only "*signal process started*." I have verified that the folder permissions are set to 755 and the file permissions are 644.

Can you see where my errors are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both your configuration files are configured to listen on the same port (80), the requests are sent to the server configuration which has `default_server` marked in it, which is the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` configuration whose root directory is at `/usr/share/nginx/www`.

To get the expected behavior, you can follow one of these options:

1. Mark the testsitea server configuration as `default_server` and remove the same from the default configuration file.
2. Change the listening port of testsitea configuration and try to connect to it using the specified port.
3. Add these entries in the /etc/hosts file in the system from which you are trying to connect from:

`192.168.1.45 mytest`

`192.168.1.45 vmhost`

and connect to the websites as `http://mytest` or `http://vmhost` as suggested previously by  @alexeyten

Comment: In my particular scenario of hosting multiple development Websites on the NGINX server, it wouldn't be efficient to set one of them as the default_server. For the same reason, having a variety of listen ports would be cumbersome. I've got things working with the additions to my _C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts_ file. I'll work to replace the IP address (which may periodically change) to a more permanent name.

Answer (score 0):

You defined server `mytest`, but request **page** `/mytest` from default server.

You have to add string

```
192.168.1.45    mytest
```

to yours `/etc/hosts` file and point your browser to `http://mytest/`.

Comment: That _does_ work although I was hoping to avoid the use of a particular IP address in the _C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts_ file. I think that I can find a way to use a symbolic or host name.